# r - lapply, ifelse and trying to compare row vs previous row in one column

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply, cbind

Forgive me in advance for trying to use my excel logic in R, but I can't seem to figure this out. In a function, given X I am trying to find out if the row prior to it has a greater value or not using simple logic. If it is, show in the new column as "yes" if not "no".

Here is the sample data:

```
temp <- data
GetFUNC<- function(x){
         temp <- cbind(temp, NewCol = ifelse(temp[2:nrow(temp),8] > temp[1:(nrow(temp)-1),8], "yes","no"))
         write.csv(temp, file = paste0(x,".csv"))
}
lapply(example,GetFUNC)
```

Just so you can see column 8 it looks like this:

```
testdata$numbers
 [1] 32216510 10755328  8083097  6878500  8377025  6469979 10675856  8189887  5337239
[10]  5156737
```

The error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 11, 10
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: your NewCol is missing the first element. You can try `NewCol = c(NA, ifelse[2:...   )`. Also, where are you using your `x`? what is `example`?

Comment: Also, take a look at `?diff` - which will return the `diff`erence between values. So you can do `c(NA,diff(nums) < 0)` for instance.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems:

- You don't need `lapply` since all the operations you are using are already vectorized.
- `:` binds more tightly than `-` (see `?Syntax`) so `1:(nrow(temp)-1` means `(1:(nrow(temp))-1`.  You want `1:(nrow(temp)-1)`   For example, compare these:

  ```
  3:5-1
  ## [1] 2 3 4

  (3:5) - 1   # same
  ## [1] 2 3 4

  3:(5-1)    # different
  ## [1] 3 4
  ```
- even if the last one is corrected your `ifelse` expression returns a vector which is one smaller than the number of rows in testdata.  Add on an NA at the beginning.

**1)** Even better would be this assuming the input data frame is `testdata` and defined as in the Note at the end:

```
transform(testdata, NewCol = c(NA, ifelse(diff(numbers) < 0, "yes", "no")))
```

giving:

```
    numbers NewCol
1  32216510   <NA>
2  10755328    yes
3   8083097    yes
4   6878500    yes
5   8377025     no
6   6469979    yes
7  10675856     no
8   8189887    yes
9   5337239    yes
10  5156737    yes
```

**2)** The above is likely what you want but here is a second solution using rollapplyr in the zoo package. It takes a rolling window of length 2 and performs a diff on each one filling the first value with NA.

```
library(zoo)

transform(testdata, New = ifelse(rollapplyr(numbers, 2, diff, fill = NA) < 0, "yes", "no"))
```

**Note:** The input `testdata` in reproducible form is:

```
testdata <- data.frame(numbers = c(32216510, 10755328, 8083097, 6878500, 
    8377025 , 6469979, 10675856, 8189887, 5337239, 5156737))
```

Comment: I like solution 1 the best, but it isn't working in the lapply. When I try it in the above function it is returning "no" for every row. However, if I isolate it like you have listed there, it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: If your problem is to produce a yes or no for each element in the numbers column of testdata then, as stated at the top of the answer, you don't need `lapply`.  If the problem is otherwise then please clarify.

Comment: My fault, I left out a step in the lapply which is to save to CSV. So I was hoping it would work within lapply.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution using `lag` to look at the previous row and `mutate` to add the new column.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(numbers = c(32216510, 10755328, 8083097, 6878500, 8377025,
                               6469979, 10675856, 8189887, 5337239, 5156737))

df1 %>% 
  mutate(NewCol = ifelse(lag(numbers) > numbers, "yes", "no"))

    numbers NewCol
1  32216510   <NA>
2  10755328    yes
3   8083097    yes
4   6878500    yes
5   8377025     no
6   6469979    yes
7  10675856     no
8   8189887    yes
9   5337239    yes
10  5156737    yes
```